# Generating a URL to a service in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

How would I generate a URL to a specific service defined in ServiceStack?

I want to include full or relative URLs to other endpoints as part of the response DTO. `RestServiceBase` contains `RequestContext.AbsoluteUri`, but that is entirely dependent on the request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Reverse Routing](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#reverse-routing)

The [Reverse Routing](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#reverse-routing) section in the wiki shows how to use extension methods on a popualated **Request DTO** to generate relative and absolute URI's:

If you use `[Route]` metadata attributes (as opposed to the Fluent API) you will be able to generate strong-typed URI's using just the DTOs, letting you create urls outside of ServiceStack web framework as done with .NET Service Clients using the `ToUrl(HttpMethod)` and `ToAbsoluteUri(HttpMethod)`, e.g:

```
[Route("/reqstars/search", "GET")]
[Route("/reqstars/aged/{Age}")]
public class SearchReqstars : IReturn<ReqstarsResponse>
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
}

var relativeUrl = new SearchReqstars { Age = 20 }.ToGetUrl();
var absoluteUrl = new SearchReqstars { Age = 20 }.ToAbsoluteUri();

relativeUrl.Print(); //=  /reqstars/aged/20
absoluteUrl.Print(); //=  http://www.myhost.com/reqstars/aged/20
```

The **Email Contacts** demo shows an example of using the above Reverse Routing extension methods to [populate routes for HTML Forms and Links in Razor Views](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/EmailContacts#bootstrap-forms).

#### Other Reverse Routing Extension methods

```
new RequestDto().ToPostUrl();
new RequestDto().ToPutUrl();
new RequestDto().ToDeleteUrl();
new RequestDto().ToOneWayUrl();
new RequestDto().ToReplyUrl();
```

### Accessing Http Request

You can also inspect the incoming underlying httpRequest with:

```
var httpReq = base.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>();
```

As well as the underlying ASP.NET (or HttpListener) Request object with:

```
var aspNetReq = httpReq.OriginalRequest;
```

They should contain additional properties that should be more useful.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking to do.